# Cannot select term in required managed metadata column in Word Document Information Panel?

Tags: managed-metadata, word, document-info-panel

I have created a custom contenttype. Inside this ct I have a managed metadata field which is required. When I try to create a new word document by the ribbon (so NOT uploading an existing word document), it looks like everything is working fine. When I click on save I got an popup which shows the SharePoint document library. I click on save. I got an popup which says there are required fields. But it is not possible to fill in the required managed metadata column!!

It is greyed out and has some dutch warning. Translated in english:

> Set property on the server.

I am using sp 2013 and office 2007. Is this an compatibility issue? Does it work only in office 2013?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works fine with Office 2013, I used the Enterprise keyword column, and it was ok. Seems like it's something with Word 2007 that's not compatible with this column type.

Comment: yes, in Office 2013 it works. So manged metadata columns dont work in office 2007 document information panel.

Comment: Will the Library columns be reflected while creating new document file in office online?