# Sharepoint metadata greyed out in Excel file

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, excel, document-info-panel

We are using SharePoint 2013 and Excel 2013, together with Managed Metadata using content types.  Some Excel 2013 users are intermittently experiencing greyed out managed metadata fields.  They only experienced this problem following an upgrade to their computers - possibly they lost some settings (in Excel?).  For their 2 colleagues, also using Excel 2013, there is no issue.

The users are accountants and wish to update an existing file to make it into a file for the new month.  From SharePoint, they open the previous month's file/check-out the file/rename/Save As 'file name + new date', then save back into SharePoint.  The problem is they can not save the file as the Managed Metadata date field can not be changed from e.g. June 2017 to July 2017, it appears greyed out.

There is a workaround: download, save to local computer.  Do the file/save as/rename the file for the new month/upload to SharePoint.  Check out file, change metadata to July 2017, save, check-in doc, done.

Any ideas as to why the metadata field is unavailable when opening a file from SharePoint, renaming it and doing a file/save as back to SP?

*additional info 14 Sept:  I found another post relating to [greyed-out meta-data](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165445/cannot-select-term-in-required-managed-metadata-column-in-word-document-informat) which relates to versions of Word, my issue is with Excel.  It then occurred to me that my colleagues upgraded to Excel 2013 and then experienced the greyed-out fields issue, but only for some files and only intermittently which is puzzling.  I've checked with the users, when they opened files in Compatibility Mode (due to it being an old Excel file type) it made no difference to the issue.

*new pictures 12/11/2018:
[image: Greyed out fields]

Managed Term Store pic - Aspect field:

[image: Managed Term Store - 'Aspect' field]

Comment: (Update - problem persists.  Possibly due to differing versions of MS Office/Excel...)

Comment: Do Windows updates or Sharepoint updates have any effect on this issue?

Comment: Still experiencing this issue intermittently. I still feel it is due to differing versions of MS Office/Excel (though I could be wrong!).

Comment: it is a long shot. But I have experienced very puzzling problem back in days of Office\SP 2007. Some of my client machines had issues saving, opening the files. It took me 2 months to nail it down to different versions of the WebDav.dll  (even though at the time XP was showing same patch level) I think from  2013(or 2010) office clients use their own version of the webDav client but comparing the version of the dll may bring some discrepancies. good Luck.